# suppress a message that was converted from an error in trycatch in R

Tags: r

In the example code, I have an error that is caught in a package I have no control over and converted as a message. I want to suppress this message in my own code base. suppressMessages() surprisingly does not work. Any ideas

```
CallDumb <- function() {
  tryCatch({
    dumb()
  }, error=function(cond){
    message(cond)})
  }

dumb <- 
function() {
  stop("This is dumb")
}

suppressMessages(CallDumb())
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be that the `cond` that is passed to your error function is not a simple string, it is a simpleError object and it seems that passing that to `message` doesn't strip it of all of it's special properties. If you extract just the message, it seems to work as expected

```
CallDumb <- function() {
  tryCatch({
    dumb()
  }, error=function(cond){
    message(conditionMessage(cond))
  })
}
suppressMessages(CallDumb())  # no output
CallDumb()
# This is dumb
```

If you cannot edit `CallDumb()` then you will have to recatch the message. Note that it will still look like an error to R.

```
tryCatch(CallDumb(), error=function(c) invisible(NULL))
```

Comment: I don't have access to the code with the trycatch so I was hoping to address it on "my side." perhaps not possible.

Comment: @user1658170 So the issue is you can't change the code for `CallDumb`?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: You could wrap `CallDumb` in *another* layer of `tryCatch`. If you put `CallDumb` in the tryCatch expression in this answer in place of `dumb` it will work as intended